# Publish Node Confirmation

Tags: 7, forms

When a user is creating content I need them to confirm (once clicking publish) that they are sure that they want to publish their post. I've been searching but cannot find an answer anywhere. I'm hoping for a modal window of some description that pops up with a message and confirm/cancel/save as draft buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Under /admin/structure/types/manage you can select the content type, and adjust the submission form settings to require preview before submitting.